# Add different constraints for different iPhones(i.e respective sizes) on launch screen

Tags: ios, storyboard, launch-screen, launchimage

I want to add different constraints for different iPhones(i.e respective sizes) on launch screen.I researched regarding this and found "varying Traits".But, this doesn't worked. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**I hope this could Help you:**

[image]

Install different size class and apply specific constrains.